# How to understand "struck"

Tags: word-meaning

"A statement made before a contract is struck that influences a party to enter into the contract"

I tried to find out what meaning of "struck" and what role in this sentence it is acting as. Is it a verb or a noun? how do understand it?

Answer (score 0):

It functions as the past tense of the word “strike”, for which one of the definitions is:

> **strike**
>
> to reach or make an agreement